# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method existeNoBanco(Login) from the type login_dao

Tags: java

to tentando fazer uma tela de login em java mas quando eu coloco o código pra autenticar da a seguinte mensagem:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method existeNoBanco(Login) from the type login_dao

```
public void autenticar() throws SQLException{
    
    String email = sistema.getT1().getText();
    String senha = sistema.getPf1().getText();
    
    Login autenticarEmail = new Login(email, senha);
    
    Connection connection = new Conexao().getConnection();  
    login_dao loginDao = new login_dao(connection);
    
    boolean existe = login_dao.existeNoBanco(autenticarEmail);
    
    if (existe){
    sistema03 sis = new sistema03();
    sis.setVisible(true);
    } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário ou Senha inválidos!");
    }
}
```

aqui ta o login_dao

```
public boolean existeNoBanco(Login login) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "select * from login where email = '" + login.getEmail() + "' and senha = '" + login.getSenha() + "';";
        PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.execute();

        ResultSet resultSet = pstm.getResultSet();
        return resultSet.next();

    }
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma solução, grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Java a convenção é declarar classes em "CamelCase" (primeira letra de cada palavra maiúscula). Por exemplo, em vez de `login_dao` a classe dever-se-ia chamar `LoginDao`.

Se seguir a convenção, poderá perceber que está chamando o método `existeNoBanco()` como se fosse um método estático (de classe), com o nome da classe antes do nome do método:

```
login_dao.existeNoBanco()
```

Troque por

```
loginDao.existeNoBanco()
```

que é o nome da variável e portanto da referência à instância (objeto) dessa classe, que permite chamar métodos de instância (não-estáticos).

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa solução foi muito útil

Comment: Por nada, mas a forma correta de agradecer no site, caso a resposta tenha sido útil, é _aceitando_ a resposta (clique no "v" verde do lado esquerdo da resposta).